# Do we have any redirect solution for all of subURL?

Tags: redirects, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Suppose I redirect `exmpale0.com` to `example1.com` , `example1.com` is newer. Already , I promoted my `exmpale0.com` into social networks , Suppose I had:

```
http://example0.com/blahblah
```

Now I have

```
‍http://exmpale1.com/blahblah‍
```

When I use `http://example0.com`, It can redirect to `example1.com` but I need to every URL what I promote into internet work fine,

Question is, Do you have any redirect solution for all of subURL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do a blanket redirect from one domain to another.

Assuming Apache, put in your .htaccess file in the root directory of example0.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect all requests from 0 to 1 and keep the original request URI.

Comment: I added your code to `.htaccess` and when i request `http://example0.com/%D8%AD%D9%84-%D9%85%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-briefly-unavailable-for-scheduled-maintenance-check-back-in-a-minute-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%B3/`  I get the following error : The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Oh thnk you , I eliminated my some code in .htaccess file.